# I am unsure why global variable won't update when accessed in class

Tags: python, class, global-variables, global

Global variable will not update after I update the global variable within the function setProdID inside of the class Product. I add 1 to it, to make a new Product ID but it always stays at 0, then 1 gets added to it.

```
prodIDCounter = 0

class NameType:
  def __init__(self, nameUse):
    self.nameUse = nameUse

class Product:
  def __init__(self, prodName, price):
    self.prodName = prodName
    self.price = price
  def setProdName(self, newProdName):
    self.prodName = newProdName
  def setReview(self, review):
    self.review = review
  def setPrice(self, price):
    self.price = price
  #Whenever a new product is created, it gets a unique prodID, that increments by 1 each time   
  def setProdID():
    global prodIDCounter
    prodIDCounter += 1
    return prodIDCounter
  review = ""
  prodID = setProdID()

class Audio(Product):
  def __init__(self, prodName, price, NameType):
    self.prodName = prodName
    self.price = price
    self.singer = NameType.nameUse
  def setGenre(self, genre):
    self.genre = genre
  def printInfo(self):
    print("[Music]")
    print("Product ID: " + str(self.prodID) + "  Product Name: " + self.prodName)   
    print("Price: $" + str(self.price) + "  Product Review Rate: " + str(self.review))
    print("Singer Name: " + self.singer)
    print("Genre: " + self.genre + "\n")
  genre = ""
    
class Cart:
  def __init__(self, NameType):
    self.owner = NameType.nameUse
  def addItem(self, Product):
    self.purchasedItems.append(Product.prodID)
  def removeItem(self, prodIDRemove):
    pass
  def displayCart():
    pass
  MAX_ITEMS = 7
  purchasedItems = []
  

#----------------------------------------------
#Create my cart here, Start of Main Test Driver
name1 = NameType("Bailey")
myCart = Cart(name1)
print(myCart.owner)

name1 = NameType("Music Artst")
music1 = Audio("Song Name", 5.50, name1)
music1.setReview(8.2)
music1.setGenre("Pop")
music1.printInfo()

name1 = NameType("Music Artist 2")
music2 = Audio("Song Name 2", 6, name1)
music2.setReview(7)
music2.setGenre("Punk")
music2.printInfo()

myCart.addItem(music1)
myCart.addItem(music2)
print(myCart.purchasedItems)
```

My code read out is:
Bailey
[Music]
Product ID: 1  Product Name: Song Name
Price: $5.5  Product Review Rate: 8.2
Singer Name: Music Artst
Genre: Pop

[Music]
Product ID: 1  Product Name: Song Name 2
Price: $6  Product Review Rate: 7
Singer Name: Music Artist 2
Genre: Punk

[1, 1]

I have tried multiple ways of doing it, but it never update the global variable and I am at a loss for what I should do. I keep geting the productID reading as 1 for all of the catalog entries. It adds the 1, but then forgets about it when prodIDCounter is called again when I make a new object.

Comment: "prodId" is bound to the class while the other variables are bound to an instance (with "self.").

Comment: @MichaelButscher But what does that have to do with the fact the global variable won't update?

Comment: "setProdID" is only called once when the class is created instead of calling it each time when an object is created.